# Couldn't add relative path of README.md to Sphinx using recommonmark

Tags: python, python-sphinx

As M2R is deprecated in Sphinx3. I tried to use recommonmark in order to include README.md to my documentation.

I have the following structure

```
project
|--README.md
|--docs
|--|--conf.py
|--|--index.rst
|--|--...
```

In `conf.py` I added `recommonmark` to extensions. and have '.md' in the `source_suffix`

In the `index.rst`

I have

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2


   ../README.md
   modules
```

But Sphinx couldn't find it:

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'README'
```

I can solve it by creating a softlink of README to the docs folder. But this doesn't seem quite right for version control. As I worries the build will break on other machines, or in future changes of configuration.

So is there a way to include README.md from the project directory to `index.rst`?

Many thanks

Comment: Notice that recommonmark is deprecated in favor of myst-parser https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

You can use an indirection.

### index.rst

```
.. toctree::
    
    readme
```

### readme.rst

```
.. include:: ../README.md
```

Pyramid docs do [this](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blame/master/docs/index.rst#L189).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. It complain read.rst has no title. It i added a title. README.md is directly loaded as rst, which messed up all the formatting. In Pyramid it doesn't have the issue because all files are rst... Before with m2r, I can use mdinclude:: instead of include::, but now it is no longer supported.

Comment: The indirection works, otherwise you would not get a new error regarding the syntax of your README.md. Please edit your question with the source of your README.md so I can help further. Another option is to run a script that converts your README.md to valid reST when you build docs and put it in your docs directory.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution so far?