# How to link a Table of Contents (TOC) from index.rst to README.rst?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, code-documentation

I have some sphinx documentation inside my `docs/` folder. There I have a typical structure of some handwritten and dynamically generated documentation from code (Python). I would like to have a very simple `README.rst` for people opening the repo. In that `README.rst` I would like to have the whole TOC displayed of the Sphinx documentation. It would look something like that:

```
About section etc.
==================

blah blah blah

For more check out the documentation

.. here the automatically imported TOC tree
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728369/2214933

Answer (score 0):

For a table of contents in Sphinx you should use `toctree`:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   doc1
   doc2
   etc..
```

And if you generate all docs, then it's nice to use "globbing" to include everything automatically:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :glob:

   *
```

For more details look into the [docs about toc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#table-of-contents)

---

here's an example in [cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)

[image]

and here's an [index.rst file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cython/cython/master/docs/index.rst)
[image]

Comment: @John if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.